# UITableView repeating checkmarks

Tags: iphone, uitableview, sdk

I have a UITableView that contains a list of countries, where the user can select multiple cells. However, when I click on a cell, every eighth cell gets a checkmark placed next to it as well! I have no idea why that is happening, and it's just the checkmark. The code attached to the eighth cell is not firing, so it's just a visual thing. Please help! Here is my code for the didSelectRow of the table:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([selectedCell accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
        int selectedRow = indexPath.row;
        NSString *intString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", selectedRow];
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"0"] ) {

            NSString *countriestill = countriesselected;
            if ([countriesselected length] == 0) {
                 countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"AR"];
            }
            else {
            countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"-AR"];
        }
        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"1"] ) {

            NSString *countriestill = countriesselected;
            if ([countriesselected length] == 0) {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"AU"];
            }
            else {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"-AU"];
            }
        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"2"] ) {

            NSString *countriestill = countriesselected;
            if ([countriesselected length] == 0) {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"BR"];
            }
            else {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"-BR"];
            }
        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"3"] ) {

            NSString *countriestill = countriesselected;
            if ([countriesselected length] == 0) {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"CA"];
            }
            else {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"-CA"];
            }
        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"4"] ) {

            NSString *countriestill = countriesselected;
            if ([countriesselected length] == 0) {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"CZ"];
            }
            else {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"-CZ"];
            }
        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"5"] ) {

            NSString *countriestill = countriesselected;
            if ([countriesselected length] == 0) {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"FR"];
            }
            else {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"-FR"];
            }
        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"6"] ) {
            NSString *countriestill = countriesselected;
            if ([countriesselected length] == 0) {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"DE"];
            }
            else {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"-DE"];
            }
        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"7"] ) {

            NSString *countriestill = countriesselected;
            if ([countriesselected length] == 0) {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"GB"];
            }
            else {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"-GB"];
            }
        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"8"] ) {

            NSString *countriestill = countriesselected;
            if ([countriesselected length] == 0) {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"HK"];
            }
            else {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"-HK"];
            }
        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"9"] ) {

            NSString *countriestill = countriesselected;
            if ([countriesselected length] == 0) {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"IN"];
            }
            else {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"-IN"];
            }
        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"10"] ) {

            NSString *countriestill = countriesselected;
            if ([countriesselected length] == 0) {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"IE"];
            }
            else {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"-IE"];
            }
        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"11"] ) {

            NSString *countriestill = countriesselected;
            if ([countriesselected length] == 0) {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"IL"];
            }
            else {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"-IL"];
            }
        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"12"] ) {

            NSString *countriestill = countriesselected;
            if ([countriesselected length] == 0) {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"IT"];
            }
            else {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"-IT"];
            }
        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"13"] ) {

            NSString *countriestill = countriesselected;
            if ([countriesselected length] == 0) {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"JP"];
            }
            else {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"-JP"];
            }
        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"14"] ) {

            NSString *countriestill = countriesselected;
            if ([countriesselected length] == 0) {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"MX"];
            }
            else {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"-MX"];
            }
        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"15"] ) {

            NSString *countriestill = countriesselected;
            if ([countriesselected length] == 0) {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"NL"];
            }
            else {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"-NL"];
            }
        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"16"] ) {
                     NSString *countriestill = countriesselected;
            if ([countriesselected length] == 0) {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"NZ"];
            }
            else {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"-NZ"];
            }
        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"17"] ) {

            NSString *countriestill = countriesselected;
            if ([countriesselected length] == 0) {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"PL"];
            }
            else {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"-PL"];
            }
        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"18"] ) {

            NSString *countriestill = countriesselected;
            if ([countriesselected length] == 0) {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"RU"];
            }
            else {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"-RU"];
            }
        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"19"] ) {
            NSString *countriestill = countriesselected;
            if ([countriesselected length] == 0) {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"ZA"];
            }
            else {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"-ZA"];
            }
        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"20"] ) {

            NSString *countriestill = countriesselected;
            if ([countriesselected length] == 0) {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"KR"];
            }
            else {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"-KR"];
            }
        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"21"] ) {

            NSString *countriestill = countriesselected;
            if ([countriesselected length] == 0) {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"ES"];
            }
            else {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"-ES"];
            }
        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"22"] ) {
            NSString *countriestill = countriesselected;
            if ([countriesselected length] == 0) {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"SE"];
            }
            else {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"-SE"];
            }
        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"23"] ) {

            NSString *countriestill = countriesselected;
            if ([countriesselected length] == 0) {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"TW"];
            }
            else {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"-TW"];
            }
        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"24"] ) {

            NSString *countriestill = countriesselected;
            if ([countriesselected length] == 0) {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"US"];
            }
            else {
                countriesselected = [countriestill stringByAppendingString:@"-US"];
            }
        }

    }
    else {
        [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
        int selectedRow = indexPath.row;
        NSString *intString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", selectedRow];
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"0"] ) {
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-AR"
                                                 withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"AR-"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"AR"
                                                                             withString:@""];

        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"1"] ) {
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-AU"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"AU-"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"AU"
                                                                             withString:@""];

        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"2"] ) {
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-BR"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"BR-"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"BR"
                                                                             withString:@""];

        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"3"] ) {
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-CA"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"CA-"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"CA"
                                                                             withString:@""];

        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"4"] ) {
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-CZ"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"CZ-"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"CZ"
                                                                             withString:@""];

        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"5"] ) {
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-FR"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"FR-"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"FR"
                                                                             withString:@""];

        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"6"] ) {
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-DE"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"DE-"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"DE"
                                                                             withString:@""];

        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"7"] ) {
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-GB"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"GB-"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"GB"
                                                                             withString:@""];

        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"8"] ) {
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-HK"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"HK-"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"HK"
                                                                             withString:@""];

        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"9"] ) {
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-IN"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"IN-"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"IN"
                                                                             withString:@""];

        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"10"] ) {
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-IE"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"IE-"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"IE"
                                                                             withString:@""];

        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"11"] ) {
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-IL"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"IL-"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"IL"
                                                                             withString:@""];

        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"12"] ) {
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-IT"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"IT-"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"IT"
                                                                             withString:@""];
        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"13"] ) {
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-JP"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"JP-"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"JP"
                                                                             withString:@""];

        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"14"] ) {
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-MX"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"MX-"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"MX"
                                                                             withString:@""];

        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"15"] ) {
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-NL"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"NL-"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"NL"
                                                                             withString:@""];

        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"16"] ) {
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-NZ"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"NZ-"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"NZ"
                                                                             withString:@""];

        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"17"] ) {
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-PL"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"PL-"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"PL"
                                                                             withString:@""];

        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"18"] ) {
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-RU"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"RU-"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"RU"
                                                                             withString:@""];

        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"19"] ) {
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-ZA"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"ZA-"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"ZA"
                                                                             withString:@""];

        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"20"] ) {
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-KR"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"KR-"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"KR"
                                                                             withString:@""];

        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"21"] ) {
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-ES"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"ES-"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"ES"
                                                                             withString:@""];

        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"22"] ) {
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-SE"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"SE-"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"SE"
                                                                             withString:@""];

        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"23"] ) {
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-TW"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"TW-"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"TW"
                                                                             withString:@""];

        }
        if ([intString isEqualToString: @"24"] ) {
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-US"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"US-"
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"US"
                                                                             withString:@""];


        }
    }
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];


}
```

Comment: Would you like to refactor your 48 identical code fragments? It's very looong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you're not familiar with the word "refactor", it means (in this case) to avoid repeating yourself in code.  There are some very good tutorials about "DRY programming" online.  As an example, without changing anything else in your program, below is your code in about 30 lines, versus 500+ lines.  In addition to being shorter, it also means that if you make a change, you only have to make it once rather than 24 or 48 times.  Finally, it makes it much easier to see what you're doing.

In particular, I agree with trydis, that your problem is certainly not in this code, but in your cellForRowAtIndexPath.  After you either pull a cell off the queue or create it, [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone]  Otherwise, the dequeued cells will have whatever accessory was in that cell when it disappeared off the screen.  The eight probably comes from having eight cells on the screen at once, so your checked cell disappears off the top, and "reappears" at the bottom.

As a final comment, building your country code string in realtime is a little ugly (hence all the stuff about hyphens).  Might be better to keep the list of active codes in an NSMutableSet and then add the hyphens when you're about to display it. ([[countriesSelected allObjects] componentsJoinedByString@"-"]

```
    NSArray * countryCodes = 
    [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"AR",@"AU",@"BR",@"CA",@"CZ",@"FR",@"DE",@"GB",@"HK",@"IN",@"IE",@"IL",@"IT",
     @"JP",@"MX",@"NL",@"NZ",@"PL",@"RU",@"ZA",:@"KR",@"ES",@"SE",@"TW",@"US",nil];

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


    NSString *countryCode = [countryCodes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([selectedCell accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
        if ([countriesselected length] == 0) {
            countriesselected = countryCode;
        } else {
            countriesselected = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@",countriesselected,countryCode]];  // note change to include hyphen

        }

    } else {
        [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@",countryCode]
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-",countryCode]
                                                                             withString:@""];
            countriesselected = [countriesselected stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:countryCode"
                                                                             withString:@""];

    }
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
```

CODE FOR cellForRowAtIndePath:

```
 NSString *countryCode = [countryCodes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 if ([countriesselected rangeOfString: countryCode].location != NSNotFound) {
     [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
 } else {
     [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
 }
```

Comment: thanks so much for your help! As you can probably tell, I am an amateur iPhone programmer, so I am kind of learning as I program. Can you help me with my cellForRowAtIndexPath? If I implement [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone], nothing is getting checked. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, each cell needs to be set with the appropriate accessoryType.  If you make the countryCodes array above global (or a property), then your cellForRowAtIndexPath could include the code segment I've added at the bottom of the above code...

Comment: To clarify, your data "model" needs to tell each cell which ones have a check mark.  If your data model is a string, then look in the string to find each country or not.

Comment: You're welcome; glad to help.  Did you try going to NSMutableSet?

Answer (score 1):

The code is in desperate need for some refactoring, but i'm gonna go out on a limb and guess that the problem is caused by cell reuse. Are you using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method? If so, remember to set the correct accessoryType there each time it's called, not when you create the cell.

Comment: Thanks! Where would I set the correct accessoryType? Because I am unable to get just one cell to be checked. Either all of them are getting selected, or none of them are.